# Communication between Safari 10 App Extension and parent application

Tags: swift, macos, safari, safari-extension

I'm creating a new Safari App Extension with the Safari 10 and Xcode 8 betas. This is working fine and I can communicate between the injected JavaScript and the App Extension.

But I also want to communicate between the App Extension and the parent application. I could not find any information about this in the documentation, it's all about communicating between the JavaScript and the native App Extension code.

Has anybody tried this or knows, how to communicate between the native App Extension code and the parent application?

Comment: the 'parent' application has his own life. app extension is running on behalf of any host application, even though your 'parent application' doesn't run. if you need to share some data between your app extension and your 'parent' application, you can do it via application group. still, app extension is totally independent of your 'parent' application.

Comment: You're right, cheers for your comment. Seems like I have to rethink my concept with the App Extension.